# Why couldn't I find sysmon events in Event Viewer?

Tags: windows, powershell, event-viewer

I installed [sysmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon) using the below commmand as documented

```
sysmon64.exe -accepteula -i
```

And I can confirm it's running with the command `Get-Service Sysmon64` in PowerShell. However I couldn't see anything in *Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Sysmon/Operational* in Event Viewer as said in the document

> On Vista and higher, events are stored in "Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Sysmon/Operational", and on older systems events are written to the System event log. Event timestamps are in UTC standard time.

even though there were already lots of events happened and I can list them by running `Get-WinEvent -LogName 'microsoft-windows-sysmon/operational'` in PowerShell. I don't see them in the `System` event log either

Why is that and where can find them in Event Viewer?

The "Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows" branch in my Event Viewer only contains these folders

[image: Event Viewer "Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows" branch]

Comment: Have you already restarted? I believe the eventlog service won't write to the log location until the boot-start driver is running.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale no, I only start the sysmon service. If a restart is required then why `Get-WinEvent` can obtain the required logs? What's the difference between it and Event Viewer?